# How to make these 2 sql queries into one?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select count(*) from sdrp15_cosd where sd_code 
in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log 
where QA_DATE IS null);

select count(*) from sdrp15_cosd where sd_code 
in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log 
where QA_DATE IS not null);
```

How do I make these 2 queries into one in SQL only.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `union all`.

```
select count(*) as count
from sdrp15_cosd 
where sd_code in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log where QA_DATE IS null)
union all
select count(*) 
from sdrp15_cosd 
where sd_code in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log where QA_DATE IS not null)
```

Edit:

```
select 
case when sd_code in 
(select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log where QA_DATE IS null) then count(*) end 
as count_null,
case when sd_code in
(select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log where QA_DATE IS not null) then count(*) end 
as count_not_null
from sdrp15_cosd
```

Comment: Is there anyways of putting it into 2 columns and not one extra row?

Comment: see the modified version.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `sdrp15_submission_log.sd_code` is not duplicated, you can easily do this with one query and conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*) - count(l.QA_DATE), count(l.QA_DATE)
from sdrp15_cosd c join
     sdrp15_submission_log l
     on c.sd_code = l.sd_code ;
```

Comment: @JeffreyKemp . . . Either the question was originally tagged MySQL or I misread it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting two row counts for QA_DATE IS null and QA_DATE IS NOT null then I don't see why you can't just do

```
select 
    (select count(*) from sdrp15_cosd where sd_code in (select sd_code from
     sdrp15_submission_log where QA_DATE IS null)) as QA_DATE_NULL
    ,(select count(*) from sdrp15_cosd where sd_code in (select sd_code from 
    sdrp15_submission_log where QA_DATE IS not null)) as QA_DATE_NOTNULL
```

Comment: for some reason i am getting the error 
                                                                        *
Error at line 5
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: are you not using SQL Server? sql server queries don't require a from clause. I.E you should be able to do a "select 0 as zero"